# Finding all users which appears in ALL departments in SQL server?

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have Table `Users`

I also have Table `Departments`

And I have a map table between `Users` and `Departments`.

I want to find all users **name** and **Id** which appears in **all** departments.

for example if  there's 5 departments and Paul is only in department #1 , so Paul will not be in the output list.

He would , only if he is listed in all departments (1..5)

I started doing something which is very long (readly long) using temp table and I assume there is a better way.

I also create a [**Sql Fiddle**](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a960/3).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's more than one way of doing this.

You could require that the number of departments that the user is in equals the total number of departments:

```
SELECT
    * 
FROM
    Users
    INNER JOIN 
    (
        SELECT userId, COUNT(*) c FROM MapUserstoDepartments
        GROUP BY userId
        HAVING COUNT(*) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Departments)
    ) UsersInAllDepartments
    ON Users.userId = UsersInAllDepartments.userId
```

You could require that removing the user's departments from the list of all departments leaves nothing:

```
SELECT * 
FROM Users
WHERE NOT EXISTS 
  (
    SELECT depId FROM Departments
    EXCEPT
    SELECT depId FROM MapUserstoDepartments WHERE userId = Users.userId
  )
```

I'm sure there are others.

Answer (score 1):

Try this

```sql
SELECT u.userId, u.UserName 
FROM MapUserstoDepartments m INNER JOIN
     Users u ON u.userId = m.userId
GROUP BY u.userId, u.UserName 
HAVING COUNT(m.depId) = (SELECT COUNT(*) FROM Departments)
```

That will produce

```
| USERID | USERNAME |
---------------------
|    100 |     John |
```

And [sqlfiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a960/68)

Answer (score 1):

You can do it like this:

```
select  u.* 
from    Users u
where not exists
(
    select  1 
    from    Departments d 
    where   not exists
    ( 
      select  1 
      from    MapUserstoDepartments m 
      where   d.depId = m.depId
      and     m.userId = u.userId
     )
)
```

**[SQL Fiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a960/88/0)**

Answer (score 0):

Is this what you want?

```
Select Tbl.userID , Tbl.username from (Select u.userid , u.username ,  
count(u.userid)  as Count from MapUsersToDepartments m
inner join Users u on m.UserID = u.userID
group by u.userid , u.username)Tbl
where Tbl.Count = (Select count(*) from Departments)
```

Here is the fiddle

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!3/5a960/53

Answer (score 0):

```
select
  Users.userId,
  count(Departments.depId),
  count(MapUserstoDepartments.userId)

from
  Users
  left join MapUserstoDepartments on MapUserstoDepartments.userId = Users.userId
  left join Departments on Departments.depId = MapUserstoDepartments.depId


group by 
  Users.userId

having
  (SELECT COUNT(*) from Departments) = count(MapUserstoDepartments.userId)
```

Answer (score 0):

Try below query. Let me know if this will help

```
 select * from users where userid in
       (select userid from MapUserstoDepartments
       group by userid
        having count(userid) = 5)
```